# Выбор платформы для клиента.

Tags: python, c++

Необходимо организовать клиентское приложение , которое будет работать с api сайта. Api необычное ,фреймворков готовых в любом случае нет. Не могу определиться с платформой решения этой задачи. Варианты: веб-интерфейс, клиент на python. Второй вариант смущает из-за того , что язык скриптовый. Кому то будет банально лень установить runtime,да и защитить программу не получится. Что посоветуете господа ?

p.s. Знаю c++ на уровне CLI приложений. На этом же уровне D.

Comment: А зачем защищать программу работающую с api? Что в нём необычного? Какой протокол общения?

Comment: Программа в своем роде уникальна и предполагается не бесплатное распространение.

Comment: Обфусцировать можно что угодно, но один пес отреверсят, если надо будет. Хоть на крестах, хоть на пистоне, хоть на чем. Имеют полное право, в общем-то. Причем чем сильнее «затянуты гайки» и чем интереснее защита, тем быстрее проанализируют. Это все при условии известности и полезности, разумеется — неизвестное или бесполезное никто ковырять не будет.

IMHO — если сервис уникальный — продавайте услугу (доступ к API и его функцональность), а не ПО. Хотя, конечно, бизнес-планы у всех свои. Но если уникален только клиентский софт, а не сервис — так и говорите.

Answer (score 2):

используйте веб-интерфейс, если не можете понять, зачем вам нужен клиент.

а так это будет удобнее и в плане кроссплатформенности, и, раз уж вы так трясетесь за свой код, то он будет у вас и под вашим контролем, а не у клиента :)

Comment: Тут стоит отметить, что код фронтэнда (пусть и возможно обфусцированный) как раз будет в полнейшем клиентском распоряжении. :)

Comment: так не делайте логики на фронтенде..
к тому же, запросы к апи, сделанные со своего компа -- не проблема посмотреть.

Comment: За свой код трясусь , ибо пишется не под заказчика и продукт должен приносить доход, хотя бы пол года. Потом и в opensource переносить можно.

Comment: ну тогда мне кажется самым надежным сделать веб-морду, просто из енё дёргать апи не напрямую, а вызывать функции в контроллере, которые и будут дёргать само апи